# Merging two DataFrames in chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

**Objective**

What would be the best approach to merge `df1` and `df2` together where `df2` is merged in by chunks. Currently getting memory error when merging in `df2`

Without chunks I do the following:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['x','y'], right_on['x','y']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the large dataframe in chunks of let's say 200K rows.

```
n = 200000  #chunk row size
list_df = [df2[i:i+n] for i in range(0, df2.shape[0],n)]
```

Then merge all the chunked df's with df1:

```
res = pd.DataFrame() 

for chunk in list_df:
    res = pd.concat([res, df1.merge(chunk, how='left', left_on=['x','y'], right_on['x','y'])
```

Comment: Both df1 and df2 are already in memory. Retrieved from an api. Any suggestions without reading in csv? @Mayank Porwal

Comment: If they are in memory already, why do you want to read them in chunks? They can be merged normally I guess.

Comment: Because df2 has 228 million rows and not everything in there is needed

Comment: Do you mean, you don't need all columns from `df2`? You can try and subset `df2` with only rows and columns you do need and then merge this subsetted df2 with df1.

Comment: I need all columns, just some rows won't need merging across because they won't have the same ids in the columns merged on

Comment: Then you should drop those rows from df2. My point here is that, if `df2` can fit completely in memory, it can also be merged easily in one go without being chunked.

Comment: I agree, there is still 200milion + rows needed after dropping and still creates memory error on merge. It is weird, have not encountered this error when a `df` is in memory but does not merge across!

Answer (score 0):

The current answer does not work properly so adding some clarification. The chunk is the one that needs to be joined on. If you try joining on the unchunked df you will get duplicate rows. Let us say you want to left join df2 on df1 like below:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['x','y'], right_on['x','y']
```

Then df1 must be chunked. If df2 is chunked instead, the end result is that there will be alot of duplicate rows. I tried the opposite as proposed by the other answer and my df went from 7k rows to 24k rows because of the null space the nonjoined rows in each version of df1 merged to a chunk of df2 cause.

Thus the correct method is:

```
n = 200000  #chunk row size
list_df = [df1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, df1.shape[0],n)]

res = pd.DataFrame() 

for chunk in list_df:
    res = pd.concat([res, chunk.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['x','y'], right_on['x','y'])])
```